# Adding custom domain in Front door Premium gives error "Domain hostname cannot be updated after creation"

Tags: azure-front-door, azure-dns

We have a DNS Zone in Azure DNS. It is ci.mycompany.com. NS records in our primary (ISP managed) DNS are pointing to it.

Now I want to add a subdomain called web.ci.mycompany.com. I have tried to create it directly in Front Door but also so that I created the subdomain in Dns (with CNAME record). I always get the error Failed to create the custom domain

> Failed to create the custom domain 'web-test-mycompany-com'. Error:
> Domain hostname cannot be updated after creation.

What is the correct way to add a domain to Front door?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in my case
There is an issue with the local development environment https construction,
I want to write a method that does not use multiple level subdomain
I tried to add something like new domain m-test-a.test.com to frontDoor (existing example domain, m.test-a.test.com).

I got the same error

As I'm guessing, there seems to be some logic in frontDoor that ignores the distinction between "-" and "."

So there is no way we can solve this problem.